# How to begin creating an outlook addin that allows drag and drop of mail messages to a task pane

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I've never done an outlook addin before but have a (I hope) simple idea and the resources to get started are fairly overwhelming.

For reference I am using Visual Studio 2013 and would be targeting this add in for Outlook 2013 / 2016 (ideally with one version? I primarily will be working in c#

My Idea is fairly straightfoward I hope:

Create a task pane and populate it with list items from an outside source. This task pane should be able to show when users are in the inbox view.

users should then be able to take a message and drag it onto anyone of the list items and that should fire some background code to send the email off to process the email into an external source and perhaps set a flag or color on the email (or maybe move it to a folder...)

Thoughts on how to get started? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked out the tutorial [Walkthrough: Creating Your First VSTO Add-in for Excel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668205.aspx)? I found it extremely useful when learning VSTO for a project. Granted it is an Excel add-in, but I can't imagine an Outlook one would be that different.

Comment: I looked at a few tutorials that seemed ok but none that specifically targeted outlook :(